# Can I use a list element as a variable?

Tags: python

I want to be able to move elements of a list based on their position in the list, where that position is defined as a variable in a function that I can change. Why doesn't the below work?

```
a = list("abcd")
b = list("efgh")

def move(start,end):
       end = start
       start = "."

move(a[1],b[3])
```

Comment: You need to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html.

Comment: That’s not the issue. When I do this replacing the start and end variables with a[1] and b[3] it works. The issue is representing string placement with a variable

Comment: Because that is not C++, you cannot take reference of an integer and hope to alter it. Instead take the `list`s swap the elements within the function.

Answer (score 2):

The *values* of `a[1]` and `b[3]` are passed as arguments to `move`, not the expressions themselves. `move(a[1], b[3])` is equivalent (given the definitions of `a` and `b`) to `move("b", "h")`.

Inside the function, all you are doing is changing the values of the local names `end` and `start`, not modifying the values of `a` and `b` in any way.

To do what you appear to want, `move` needs to receive both lists in addition to the indices as arguments. For example,

```
def move(l1, l2, start, end):
     l2[end] = l1[start]
     l1[start] = "."

move(a, b, 1, 3)
```

Comment: Neither is a starting or ending point; they refer to the two lists. You need to split `a[1]` into the list being indexed (`a`) and the index itself (`1`) and pass them as separate arguments. Inside the function, you know (because you defined the parameter list) which index goes with which list. `l1` and `start` correspond to the original `start` parameter.

Comment: Please, be sure to read the link I posted as a comment on the question.